# Strange javascript color coding in Dreamwever

Tags: javascript, syntax-highlighting, dreamweaver

During writing some Javascript scripts I discovered that color coding in most of editors is nice and welcome. Before few days I tried Dreamwever CS6 and I was confused when I put this code there:

```
function fire_it(i)
{
var p=3; //comment, grey as default
var g=i/p; //comment, but black font
alert(g); /* comment, grey as default */
}
```

I thought I missed to write two slashes // as start of comment in second line and after that (now there are /// ) comment appeared as grey text but now first slash at start of comment in second line remained black! Good thing is that neither variant made no error warning, code works but could confuse newbie. Just my opinion.

Comment: Weird. But Sublime Text is much better than Dream Weaver. Lighter and kinder to your wallet...I'd change.

http://www.sublimetext.com

Comment: @Starkers: thank you for your input. I had a chance to try new DW and I noticed this "bug". DW is out of my money abilities. Thanks for suggestion, I'll check it soon.